In The Haunting of Hill House, why does Dr. Montague describe fear as "willing"
In chapter 5 of The Haunting of Hill House by Shirley Jackson, the protagonists are gathered together having experienced some disturbing phenomenon. In discussing what they have seen, one of them, Dr. Montague, says:

‘Fear,’ the doctor said, ‘is the relinquishment of logic, the willing relinquishing of reasonable patterns. We yield to it or we fight it, but we cannot meet it half-way.’

This struck me as a very peculiar statement, particularly because in my copy the word willing is italicised, as reproduced above. This would seem to mean that he is claiming they - and by extension we - are only scared because we actively choose to do so which would feel like a pretty bold claim in any circumstance, but a particularly odd one directly after the group has experienced a number of frightening supernatural phenomenon.
What is the doctor trying to imply here, and does it have any relationships to his character, or to the wider themes of the book as a whole?

For him, it is a function of a person's will. You give up any logic you might have. It's just his opinion. Not sure I think it is strange...
